# Prevent a second scroll bar appearing on the page

Tags: html, css

I've got this list items which is populated dynamically.

```
<ul style='list-style: none;' class='custom-menu list-unstyled'>
     <li id = "vi1">Volvo</li>
     <li id = "vi2">Mercedes</li>
     <li id = "vi3">Audi</li>
</ul>
```

After the list is populated, a second scroll bar appear on the page. My question is, how do I prevent the scroll bar appearing?

I'm using this css

```
.custom-menu {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #f60;
}
```

EDIT:

```
   $(document).on("contextmenu", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Show contextmenu
      $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
      });
    });
```

Screenshot in IE

[image]

Comment: looking like typo issue, the class name in style `.custom-rmenu` and used `.custom-menu`

Answer (score 1):

Use css rule `overflow: hidden;` on that second container

Comment: The outer scroll bar is the body's scroll bar, the second scroll bar is the container element scroll bar, it's hard to tell which element that is because you didn't post much code. You can find out by right clicking on the scroll bar then "inspect element"

Comment: I'm unable to inspect a scrollbar using F12?

Comment: Check all elements `width` using your console and see what's causing this overflow. Would help if you could provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not add a second scroll bar to the page, it must be part of the code that you forgot to include.

Also please fix spelling mistakes before posting code you misspelled `custom-menu` in your CSS and remove: `display: none;`.

Comment: Still not enough code to be able to see where the problem is :)